# getView() is not called in ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I am using a `CustomListView` to display contact details from database.I am not getting `ListView` in my output. `getView()` method of `CustomListViewAdapter` is not getting called.My code is,

**ViewContact** Activity

```
 final DBAdapter dba = new DBAdapter(ctx);
dba.open();
Cursor c = dba.getContact();
    if(c.moveToFirst())
{

do
    {
        idstr[i]=c.getInt(0);
        sfname[i] = c.getString(1);
        slname[i] = c.getString(2);
        smob[i] = c.getString(3);
        semail[i] = c.getString(4);
        sphoto[i]=c.getString(5);

        sname[i]=sfname[i]+" "+slname[i];


         RowItem item = new RowItem(sphoto[i],sname [i], smob[i],semail[i]);
           System.out.println(" item.."+item);
            rowItems.add(item);
            System.out.println("row item.."+rowItems);
        i++;

    }while(c.moveToNext());



} 


 CustomListViewAdapter adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(this,
         R.layout.list_item, rowItems);
            viewContact.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**Edit**
Added getCount() method and changes made in constructor as  super(context, resourceId,items);

```
public class CustomListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RowItem> {

Context context;

 public CustomListViewAdapter(Context context, int resourceId,
        List<RowItem> items) {
    super(context, resourceId,items);
    this.context = context;
}

/*private view holder class*/
private class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView txtName;
    TextView txtPhone;
    TextView txtEmail;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.getCount();
}
  @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     System.out.println("in view..");
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    RowItem rowItem = getItem(position);

    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.con_name);
        holder.txtPhone = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.con_phone);
        holder.txtEmail = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.con_email);
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.con_image);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    holder.txtName.setText(rowItem.getName());
    holder.txtPhone.setText(rowItem.getPhone());
    holder.txtEmail.setText(rowItem.getEmail());
    String str=rowItem.getImageId();
    if(str.equals("No photo"))
    {
        System.out.println("in no photo if");
        holder.imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.nophoto);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("in no photo else");
        Uri img=Uri.parse(str);
    holder.imageView.setImageURI(img);
    }
    return convertView;
}
   }
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't extend ArrayAdapter. It's bad practice. Create your own base adapter and extend that. In your case you should actually use an [CursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html) and not an list based adapter.
2. There is data in your DB, right?
3. You have an bug there (related to 1), you have to overwrite the getCount method. If you don't do that, it will use it's internal list (inheritated from ArrayList) you're completely ignoring.

Comment: Thank you. My DB contains values,I have added getCount() but i didn't get result..

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `ArrayAdapter(Context, int)` super constructor, the array in the adapter is empty. Use `ArrayAdapter(Context, int, T[])` instead, passing the array to the super constructor too.